# Reading from text file saving it and printing it out into a text

Tags: java, file, input

I hope someone can help me.

I am trying to create a program to read variables from an input file to output file 
the input file is as follows employee's first name, two double precision values, seller's salary and the total value sold by him/her.

```
JOAO
450.00
1230.30

FDJSI
333.00
2.00

MAJDIIDFH
433.00
222.50
```

The required seller's total salary is output

This is the code I have been trying to make

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 * A simple example program that reads a text file line by line and display each line.
 */
public class Salary {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;


    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("temp.txt"));
        String sellerName;


        while ((sellerName = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String  salary = br.readLine(); 
            String totalSale =br.readLine(); 
            double percentage  = 0.15;

            double  SaleAfterPercentage = totalSale * percentage; 
            //value of the total salary 
            double  finalSalary = salary +  SaleAfterPercentage ; 


        System.out.println(sellerName);
      //  System.out.println(salary);
     //    System.out.println(totalSale);
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have a Reader object... How about doing some research on writing to a file before asking on Stackoverflow, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("temp.txt"));
    String line = null;


    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer  st = new StringTokenizer(line);

        String sellerName = st.nextToken();
        String salary = st.nextToken(); 
        String totalSale =st.nextToken(); 
        double percentage  = 0.15;

        double  SaleAfterPercentage = (Double.parseDouble(totalSale)) * percentage; 
        //value of the total salary 
        double  finalSalary = Double.parseDouble(salary) +  SaleAfterPercentage ; 


    System.out.println(sellerName);

    System.out.println(finalSalary);
     System.out.println(totalSale);
    }


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

To read this

```
JOAO 450.00 1230.30
FDJSI 333.00 2.00
MAJDIIDFH 433.00 222.50
```